# How to retrieve script path in Perl? (not the running one)

Tags: perl, path, cgi

I have a CGI interface that calls a Perl plugin. Those scripts are located in different folders and the Perl one is supposed to read an XML file that is located in another folder. To make it simple I give you an example:

```
/a/b/cgi-bin/test.cgi # calls test.pl
/e/plugins/test.pl # reads config.xml
/e/etc/config.xml
```

Now I don't know how to make the Perl plugin to read the config file. Ofcourse I can't write the path on the script because tomorrow I may change the location of this file. I tryed using **Cwd** and **abs_path** on test.pl but this method returns the "running" path when instead I want the "location" path of test.pl so I can modify it in order to build the config.xml path. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Using [realpath](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) instead of abspath solved my problem, or at least it seems so, I'll do more tests.

**EDIT2:** Ok realpath works but now I have another problem... The Perl plugin uses some additional packages that I made but ofcourse now writing *use MyPackage;* doesn't work anymore because it looks on the wrong folder... Is there a way to modify the environment variable? I don't know something that will avoid me from changing thousands lines of code.

**EDIT3:** Ok solved that too somehow, I guess I will just install my packages in the INC folder so I don't have to mess up with my code anymore.

Comment: It feels like you forgot to post some information here. Such as: How do you find `test.pl` to begin with?

Comment: I have a little text file that tells test.cgi how to find the plugins.

Comment: Couldn't you pass that information (where it loaded 'test.pl' from) to whatever function you're calling in the plugin?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=40553

Comment: @TLP, I think raz3r specified that it was _not_ the running script she's interested in.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh In order to find config.xml, you need to know where test.pl is. The problem is that when calling `/e/plugins/test.pl` from `/a/b/cgi-bin/`, that is the current directory.

Comment: @TLP: raz3r mentioned that /e/ is specified in a 'text file' somewhere. And it depends how 'test.pl' is "called". Do? (yes). Require/Use? (No) Read+Eval (No)

Comment: Yes there is a file that test.cgi reads with a cat in order to retrieve the absolute path of plugins. This works fine, the problem is related to the plugins (ie test.pl) reading the config file. Anyway as I said before realpath actually works, however the documentation says that realpath is actually just a synonym for abs_path, which makes me wonder... Why the heck does it work? O_o

Comment: @raz3r Looking at the source code, it is indeed using the exact same subroutines. Either your version is different, or you are doing something different now. If you print both abs_path and realpath, do you get the same value?

Comment: Actually I do get the same value, at least now... Ok that's weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will return the path of an `used()`ed package:

```
use Cwd qw/abs_path/; 

sub get_module_folder {
  my $mkey = shift;
  $mkey =~ s|\:\:|/|g;
  $mkey .= '.pm';
  my $mpath = $INC{$mkey};
  $mpath =~ s|/[^/]+$||;
  return abs_path($mpath);
}
```

So if test.pl implements a package, say `Plugin::Foo`, then just call it as:

```
use Plugin::Foo;
open my $f, '<', get_module_folder('Plugin::Foo').'/../etc/config.xml'
  or die "can't open config file for reading: $!";
```

(Assuming that I've understood your folder structure correctly).

**Updated:** to use abs_path.

I often include this method in my own modules (replacing `shift` with `__PACKAGE__`) so that they can find any config/data they require.